# How to convert tree structure into list using MapStruct (in easy way)?

Tags: java, mapstruct

How to convert tree structure into list using MapStruct (in easy way)?

Given class `Foo`

```
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
public class Foo {

    String a;

    Bar[] bar;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Bar {
        String b;
    }

}
```

and class `Foobar`

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Foobar {
    String a;
    String b;
}
```

Let's define conversion:

```
@Mapping(target = "a", source = "foo.a")
@Mapping(target = "b", source = "bar.b")
Foobar convert(Foo foo, Foo.Bar bar);
```

### QUESTION:

**How to define conversion from Foo[] into List<Foobar>**

```
List<Foobar> convert(Foo[] foos); // <-- this is not working
```

I got:

> java: Unmapped target property: "b". Mapping from Collection element
> "Foo foo" to "Foobar foobar".

// edited

I reality my case is more complicated and it is something like:

```
class A {
  long id;
  B[] b;

  class B {
     LocalDate d;
     C[] c;
  }

  class C {
    int i;
    D[] d;
  }

  class D {
    String s;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

MapStruct can not know whether you want to convert all Foo.bar objects into separate objects or just map an explicit one.

For example:

```
List<Foobar> convert(Foo[] foos);
```

Will attempt to use a mapping method `Foobar convert(Foo foo)` and not `Foobar convert(Foo foo, Foo.Bar bar)`.

For collections you can expect that the input size equals the output size with mapstruct. So 5 Foo objects should result into 5 FooBar objects, if you want it to increase you will have to write some manual code for this, see below.

## Solution

What mapstruct does support is setting up the mapping at the detailed level, and then you need to manually call it.

For example:

```
@Mapping(target = "a", source = "foo.a")
@Mapping(target = "b", source = "bar.b")
Foobar convert( Foo foo, Foo.Bar bar );

default List<Foobar> convert( Foo[] foos ) {
  List<Foobar> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for ( Foo foo : foos ) {
    for ( Foo.Bar bar : foo.bar ) {
      result.add( convert( foo, bar ) );
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

using the more complex example:

```
@Mapping(target = "id", source = "a.id")
@Mapping(target = "date", source = "b.d")
@Mapping(target = "number", source = "c.i")
@Mapping(target = "text", source = "d.s")
Result convert( A a, B b, C c, D d );

default List<Result> convert( A[] as ) {
  List<Result> result = new ArrayList<>();
  for ( A a : as ) {
    for ( A.B b : a.b ) {
      for ( A.C c : b.c ) {
        for ( A.D d : c.d ) {
          result.add( convert( a, b, c, d ) );
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```